# How IEnumerable are stored in memory in c#?

Tags: c#, .net, memory-management

Like Array is the sequential memory allocation, and list might get stored in memory in the same way as linked list ( please correct me if i am wrong ). How IEnumerable are stored in memory in c#?
Suppose I have a class

```
 public class Employee
 {
      public int Id { get; set; }
      public string Name { get; set; }
 }
```

How the memory allocation will differ in below two cases. why compiler doesn't allow us to edit IEnumerables

```
IList<Employee> EmpList ;

Or

IEnumerables<Employee> EmpList ;
```

Comment: IEnumerable is an `interface`. It pretty much depends on concrete implementation. `Array` and `LinkedList` are also `IEnumerable` but  memory storage as you pointed out is different.

Comment: @pwas : ok, so when i use IEnumerable<T> to store the collection of object, how compiler use to allocate memory for it? is it sequential? or reference based pointer or something else?

Comment: It can be either, or something else, it depends. The interface does not imply anything.

Comment: @Shiv It depends how you use :) - please show code sample.

Comment: It is impossible to use `IEnumerable<T>` to store a collection, as the interface `IEnumerable<T>` does not permit insertion of elements; it permits reading only.

Comment: @Codor nope. `List<T>` implements `IEnumerable<T>` but list is definitely collection. I'd say ratther that IEnumerable<T> does not expose insertion interface, but it can (but don't have to, f.e. machine state) contain collection.

Comment: @pwas Of course `List<T>` permits a method to add elements, but this method does not belong to `IEnumerable<T>`.

Comment: @pwas - You can store items in any `ICollection<T>` and most (if not all) collections are also `IEnumerable<T>`. But not every `IEnumerable<T>` is a collection.

Comment: @Corak yes I know - I've putted this in the bracket in my previous comment. Anyway `IEnumerable<T>` can store collection (again: but don't have to, it can be machine state f.e), but you can't just add / remove elements. IMHO telling that `IEnumerable` stores anything it is a little bit confusing - interface cannot store anything  - it just expose memebrs to communicaate with implementation.

Comment: @shiv - again, `IList<T>` and `IEnumerable<T>` are just interfaces. It depends on the actual implementation how the items are stored. For example `List<T>` (which implements both) just happens to store the items in an underlying array. But that's just an implementation detail and could change in the future. - Also, for all reference types, only the reference is "stored" in that underlying array. The actual object data could be anywhere, randomly distributed.

Comment: @Corak: ok, I got that. thanks. helped me to clear my concept

Comment: I have edited my answer to address "why the compiler does not allow us to edit IEnumerables"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An IEnumerable variable stores an object reference (which, as an implementation detail, will be four or eight bytes, depending on the process).  The same is true of a System.Collections.Generic.List variable, an array variable, an ICollection variable, or (although not relevant to the question) any reference-type variable.

The data produced by the object's enumerator will be stored however dictated by the object to which the reference points.  In some cases, it will store only the first element along with some information used by the enumerator to calculate subsequent elements (System.Linq.Enumerable.Range, for example).  In other cases, the object could be an array or S.C.G.List (sequential storage -- lists use arrays for their storage), or a linked list, or a hash set or sorted set (which use a hash table and binary tree, respectively), or just about anything else someone wants to dream up and implement.

In your question about memory allocation, there is no difference in memory use between

```
IList<Employee> empList = new List<Employee>();
```

and

```
IEnumerable<Employee> empList = new List<Employee>();
```

The difference between these two is in the methods you can call on the object from the empList object reference.  In the first case, you are limited to the many members defined in IList and the interfaces from which it inherits, so you can mutate the collection.  In the second case, you can only call GetEnumerator, so you cannot mutate the collection.

Answer (score 6):

This question is impossible to answer.

It depends on the underlying object that implements `IEnumerable`.

It could be an array, in which case the memory representation is just that, an array, or it could be a lazily implemented enumerator that produces the values on demand, in which case it doesn't really have a memory representation other than the local variables of the state machine in that method.

Answer (score 2):

`IEnumerable` is just an *interface*, all it should do is

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc317868.aspx

to provide an enumerator:

```
 public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
```

The enumerator's implementation could be *different*, 
it could be, in fact, *no data storing* at all:

```
  // Generates 0, 1, 2, ... sequence
  public sealed class Sample: IEnumerable {
    public IEnumerator GetEnumerator() {
      for(int i = 0;; ++i)
        yield return i;
    }  
  }
```

Comment: Technically, that's storing at least an `i`, on a compiler-generated enumerator instance, and the `.Current` value... ;p